# Alternative solution for parallel numpy array application

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

`doctors` and `patients` arrays are parallel. Data says, for example, the doctor named Benitz has 172 patients in 2017, the doctor Modin has 272 patients in 2019 and so on. I'd like to extract the doctor name data for year 2019 into an array, which is `['Modin' 'Vandergard']`. I did this by the code below, but as you see, I firstly use list, `append` method and then turn the list into an array. I wonder if there is more practical solution without using lists. I mean, is there any way to solve it by just using arrays?

```
import numpy as np

doctors=np.array(['Benitz','Modin','Leabow','Vandergard'])

patients=np.array([[2017,172],
                   [2019,272],
                   [2016,203],
                   [2019,250]])

doc2019_list=[]
for row in range(0,len(patients)):
    for col in range(0,len(patients[row])):
        if patients[row][col]==2019:
            doc2019_list.append(doctors[row])
doc2019=np.array(doc2019_list)

print(doc2019)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the years:

```py
>>> patients[:,0]
[2017 2019 2016 2019]
```

...to create a boolean array of the years equivalent to `2019`:

```py
>>> patients[:,0] == 2019
[False  True False  True]
```

...and use that to access the `doctors` array:

```py
>>> doctors[patients[:,0] == 2019]
['Modin' 'Vandergard']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` functions by combining two lists.

```py
import numpy as np

doctors=np.array(['Benitz','Modin','Leabow','Vandergard'])

patients=np.array([[2017,172],
                   [2019,272],
                   [2016,203],
                   [2019,250]])

doc2019_list = [doctor for doctor, patient in zip(doctors, patients) if patient[0] == 2019]
print(doc2019_list)
```

If the `List comprehension` method seems little confusing, look below code, this is the same with above. Further reading [Python - List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```py
import numpy as np

doctors=np.array(['Benitz','Modin','Leabow','Vandergard'])

patients=np.array([[2017,172],
                   [2019,272],
                   [2016,203],
                   [2019,250]])
doc2019_list = []

for doctor, patient in zip(doctors, patients):
  if patient[0] == 2019:
    doc2019_list.append(doctor)
print(doc2019_list)
```

Another alternative way with `numpy.array`

```py
doc2019_list = np.array([doctor for doctor, patient in zip(doctors, patients) if patient[0] == 2019])
```

Comment: so, because numpy has no attribute append, we need to use lists certainly, right?

Comment: Numpy has `append` function [Numpy Append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). It is your choice, you can process with `numpy.append`. But `numpy.append` generates a new array every call, be careful.